# Preciso de ajuda para achar um erro em um programa

Tags: c, matriz

[[image: ][1]]
[image]

nessa imagem esta o código do programa, o DEV C++ apontou erros na linha 5 e na linha 6 como mostrei nas fotos abaixo
ja tentei de tudo mas não descubro o erro